# External HDD error - data recovery Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

I recently connected my external HDD to Ubuntu 12.04, but now it's not working. If I try to use ntfsfix in the terminal it gives this error message:

```
abcd@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for abcd: 
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1024  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1025  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1024  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 3 has no FILE magic (0x43425355)
Failed to open inode FILE_Volume: Input/output error FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1024  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
OK
Reading $MFTMirr... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1025  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 1024  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 3 has no FILE magic (0x43425355)
Failed to read $Volume: Input/output error
FAILED
Error setting volume flags.
```

Is it possible to recover data from the disk?

Comment: Can you elaborate upon problems for it not to be working?

Comment: i just connected it to the ubuntu 12.04 system in laptop and then turned the laptop off, so when i connected it to my desktop it says drive not accessible, so i read online that maybe its an ntfs problem so i tried ntfs fix in ubuntu again and it gave this error...

Comment: is there any way to recover the data cause i have another disk??

Comment: Just to clarify the steps, you: connected external hdd to laptop, turned off laptop, disconnected external hdd from laptop and connected to desktop pc and wasn't able to access it OR connected external hdd to laptop, turned off the laptop and then turned back on and wasn't able to access data in external hdd?

Comment: it is like this::    connected external hdd to laptop, turned off laptop, disconnected external hdd from laptop and connected to desktop pc and wasn't able to access it

Comment: alright, did external hdd work on laptop? When external hdd is connected to desktop, can you paste the output of `sudo fdisk -l` into http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and put the link back here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting an input/output error I would not suspect filesystem corruption right away(though its possible). First I would try a different cable. With the new cable try every USB port on both machines.

Does the OS even recognize when the HDD is first plugged in? If you can get the OS to recognize the HDD maybe it would be possible to use a cloning utility to clone the drive to another external HDD.

Comment: i tried different cable and it was not working ..other wise it was also giving me error actual vcn index buffer different ...what i did was use stellar windows data recovery software to transfer data to another disk...